# Why did qt-creator fail to build after I named the widget class with a lower case letter?

Tags: c++, qt, qt-creator, qwidget

I created a widget in the mainwindow and promoted it to my class, the widget was called "renderArea" and I named the class "renderArea" and got bugs. When I renamed the class to "RenderArea" it worked. Any idea why this would cause it to fail?

Comment: Did you re-run qmake after the rename?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The designer (*.ui) files are translated to headers (*.h) by the "uic" compiler. In the resulting code there is an object variable with the same name of a class. This will produce compiler errors like the ones explained in [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13333218/c-object-name-same-as-class-name). You can't apply the same solution (adding the class keyword) to your scenario, because the code is auto-generated. But it works when you renamed the class starting with an   upper-case, because the names are no longer the same (remember that C and C++ are case-sensitive).