# Variable with the same name as a class - invalid?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, name-clash

```cpp
struct A
{
};

struct B
{
  using A_t = A;
  A_t A;
};
```

This code compiles happily with `clang++` (14.0.6), while `g++` (12.2.0) issues the following error:

```
naming.cpp:8:7: error: declaration of ‘B::A_t B::A’ changes meaning of ‘A’ [-fpermissive]
    8 |   A_t A;
      |       ^
naming.cpp:1:8: note: ‘A’ declared here as ‘struct A’
    1 | struct A
      |        ^
```

So who's right? (I stumbled into this at the [abby library](https://github.com/albin-johansson/abby/blob/c4a37ea2c11c04bef85eda3b1dce6a61ded498a5/include/abby.hpp#L493).)

[In this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13333218/c-object-name-same-as-class-name) the answers deal with the type and variable (with the same name) appearing on the same line, but here this is prevented by the `using` declaration.

Comment: `struct A{}; struct B {A A;;};` also works in clang and msvc. [Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/cex9rcf48). I'm sure there are dupe(s) for this.

Comment: In Clang, yes, but neither works in GCC.

Comment: Yes, they work in clang and msvc but not in gcc.

Comment: Dup of [Declaration of method changes meaning of symbol](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15537023/declaration-of-method-changes-meaning-of-symbol)

Comment: `A_t A` is not a variable, it is an NSDM

Comment: `using A_t = ::A;` would work. Also `::A A;`. This is a "ill-formed, no diagnostic required" rule, so clang is allowed to silently compile it.